# How do I check if a specific element is visible and do task only then in CasperJS?

Tags: json, if-statement, phantomjs, visibility, casperjs

I want to check when an element becomes visible to the human eye. I have used  methods like `this.exists()` but this doesn't help as it still doesn't show.

I have finally found a way to output data that tells me whether it is visible or not using `getElementsInfo()`.

Here is what I have and the output:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var casper = require('casper').create({
  viewportSize: {width: 950, height: 950}
});

casper.start('https://example.com/check.html', function() {
    //this.captureSelector('1p.png', 'body');
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});
casper.then(function(){
    var one = casper.cli.get(0);
    var two  = casper.cli.get(1);
    this.sendKeys('input[id="txt"]',one);

    casper.waitForSelector('#txtsend', function() {
        this.click('#txtsend');
    });
    casper.waitForSelector('#Step1', function() {
        require('utils').dump(this.getElementsInfo('#Step1'));
        var a = this.fetchText('#Step1');
        this.echo(a);
    });
});

casper.run();
```

This is the output I want to check whether `visible` is true or false and if true run a command and if false run another.

```json
[
    {
        "attributes": {
            "id": "Step1"
        },
        "height": 42,
        "html": "This is ready to complete",
        "nodeName": "span",
        "tag": "<span id=\"Step1\">This is ready to complete</span>",
        "text": "This is ready to complete,
        "visible": true, // this can also be false this is what i want to fetch and monitor whether true or fals
        "width": 229,
        "x": 624,
        "y": 484
    }
]
```

Comment: Artjom no i have not let me have a look for it now in the documentation i have not seen this thanks and if you like add an answer with and example of use i will accept you answer if it does what i need testing right now

Comment: @ArtjomB. please write your comment as an answer this worked fine i dont know how i missed this in the documentation must of been trying to hard

Comment: Did my answer help? Did you have any problems with it?

Answer (score 0):

There is specifically a step function for waiting until an element on the page becomes visible which is aptly named [`waitUntilVisible()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waituntilvisible) which is only a shorthand for [`waitFor()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitfor) in conjunction with [`visible()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#visible).

In your case you would use it like this:

```
casper.waitForSelector('#txtsend', function() {
    this.click('#txtsend');
}).waitUntilVisible('#Step1', function then() {
    var a = this.fetchText('#Step1');
    this.echo(a);
    // do something
}, function onTimeout(){
    this.echo("not found");
    // do something else
});
```

You can also omit the `onTimeout` callback. If the elemen is not found, then it will stop the script.

Also, you don't need to parse anything, because the output of `getElementsInfo()` is an object which you can simply access:

```
var info = casper.getElementsInfo("#Step");
casper.echo("Is visible? " + info[0].visible);
```

You can also use `getElementInfo()` which only returns the info of the first matched element instead of an array of element infos.